# Regex match all word pairs

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to get all the word pairs out of a piece of text.

I have the following regular expression `(\w+) +(\w+)` that I run on a piece of text with no punctuation. My issue is this does not consider all possible pairs

```sh
$ echo "hello dear world" | grep -Eoi "(\w+) +(\w+)"
hello dear
```

I want the following

```sh
$ echo "hello dear world" | grep -Eoi [some expression]
hello dear 
dear world
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traditional `grep` won't return capture groups.

You can consider `pcregrep` with a lookahead and 2 capture groups:

```sh
echo "hello dear world" | pcregrep -o1 -o2 '(\w+)(?=(\h+\w+))'

hello dear
dear world
```

If you don't have `pcregrep` then you can use this simple `awk`:

```sh
awk '{for (i=1; i<NF; ++i) print $i OFS $(i+1)}' <<< "hello dear world"

hello dear
dear world
```

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, here is 1 more of doing this in `awk` program(with any version of `awk` this should be working fine).

```
echo "hello dear world" | awk '{for(i=2;i<NF;i++){$i=$i ORS $i}} 1'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, printing values by `echo` command and sending it as a standard input to `awk` program. Then in `awk` program, going through fields(only even ones), re-assigning those fields with their own value followed by new line and their own value, then printing edited/non-edited line.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and `\s` shorthand:

```
$ echo "hello dear world" | awk -v RS='\\s+' 'NR>1{print p OFS $0} {p=$0}'
hello dear
dear world
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl allows lookarounds, so you can use a common technique to match overlapping texts with a capturing group inside a positive lookahead:

```sh
perl -lne 'print "$1" while /\b(?=(\w+\s+\w+))/g' file
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/c3UtZj):

```sh
s="hello dear world"
perl -lne 'print "$1" while /\b(?=(\w+\s+\w+))/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
hello dear
dear world
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eZVx9j/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=(\w+\s+\w+))` - a positive lookahead that requires (immediately to the right of the current position):

  - `(\w+\s+\w+)` - Capturing group 1:

    - `\w+` - one or more word chars
    - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
    - `\w+` - one or more word chars

Answer (score 1):

Using [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep):

```
% echo "hello dear world" | rg '(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)' -r "$(printf '$1 $2\n$2 $3')"
hello dear
dear world
```

To do all 2 word combinations based on the 3, you can combine it with a `crunch` command, e.g.

```
% echo "hello dear world" | rg -o '(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)' -r "$(crunch 5 5 + + 123 -t '$% $%' 2>/dev/null)"
hello hello
hello dear
hello world
dear hello
dear dear
dear world
world hello
world dear
world world
```

To read more about overlap matching, see:

- [How to match all word pairs (with overlap/look-behind)?](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/discussions/2189)